# Omit index page from the Bookdown TOC

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc, bookdown

I am using bookdown to write a book with a web-version, using the bs4_book format. I want my index page (the front page) to not appear in the TOC on the left, i.e. I want the blue circled item in this screenshot not to appear in the TOC:

[image: screenshot of TOC with Preface]

I tried the directions in the [documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/toc-unlisted.html):

```
# Section name {.unlisted .unnumbered}
```

but it is to no avail. My pandoc version is > 2.7 as indicated:

```
> rmarkdown::pandoc_version()
[1] ‘2.11.0.4’
```

These are the contents of _bookdown.yaml

```
book_filename: "shiny-book"
language:
  ui:
    chapter_name: "Chapter "
delete_merged_file: true
new_session: no

rmd_files:
  [
    "index.Rmd",
    "test_chapter.md",
  ]
```

_output.yml

```
bookdown::bs4_book:
  repo: https://github.com/smsaladi/phd
  includes:
    in_header: [ga_script.html, no_robots.html]
```

index.Rmd

```
---
title: "Investigations on the computer"
author: "Name"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
---

`r if (knitr::is_latex_output()) '<!--'`

# Preface {.unlisted .unnumbered}

`r if (knitr::is_latex_output()) '-->'`
```